# Git: Partial rewrite of history, moving files into subfolder

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-repo

I have a Git repository with 2+ years of history. A few weeks ago I decided to convert this repo into a monorepo. I moved all files from the root directory into a directory `module1` and created a new directory `module2` with a new commit. Development continued a few weeks. Now I realized that it would have been a good idea to rewrite history as if all commits from day one until **before** the move commit happened in `module1`. Is this possible with [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)?

```
     A -------------- M -------------- M+x
first commit      move commit     latest commit
```

Is it possible to rewrite history of `A` until `M^1` as if everything happened in directory `module1` while keeping commits `M` until `M+x` on top of it?

Comment: Short answer is yes :) rewrite commits up to `M^` , then use `rebase --onto NewM^ M M+x`

Comment: @LeGEC Do I have to use the `--partial` option for `filter-branch`? Can you maybe provide some examples?

Comment: Don't use `filter-branch`. Use `git-filter-repo`. It has an amazing [examples page](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES) and very thorough [documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html). 
If we could ignore the _before x commit_ requirement, all you'd need would be `git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter module1/` and I found that by just skimming the examples page.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant `filter-repo` not `filter-branch`.